# Arrendondamento de valores javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de fazer uma "arredondamento" de valores dentro do javascript.

Eu sei que a função `Math.Round()` arredonda, mas só casa decimal, eu preciso das seguintes situações.

1 - De 10 em 10... Se caso o usuário digitar 155, o sistema arredonda para 160,
Se caso o usuário digitar 152 por exemplo, o sistema arredonda para 150.

2 - De 500 em 500... Se caso o usuário digitar 4300, o sistema arredonda para 4500, se caso o usuário digitar 4220, o sistema arredonda para 4000

Eu sinceramente não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Você tem algum código feito? A lógica que poderia se utilizar é por resto de divisão. Divida o numero e multiplique pela quantidade vezes que isso a divisão sem resto é possível.

Comment: Na verdade não... eu não consegui pensar em um raciocínio para isso

Comment: Qual a condição para distinguir entre as duas situações: quando usar a regra 1 e quando usar a regra 2?

Comment: É pela escolha do tipo de licenciamento do software.

Educacional de 500 em 500 e Comercial e Profissional de 10 em 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa na mesma o `Math.Round()` mas arredonda com relação à ordem de grandeza que queres:

```js
function arredondaPorOrdem(nr, ord) {
  return Math.round(nr / ord) * ord;
}

var decimas = arredondaPorOrdem(153, 10);
var cincoEmCinco = arredondaPorOrdem(153, 5);

console.log(decimas, cincoEmCinco); // 150 155
```

Answer (score 2):

Creio que está função  resolveria seu problema:

```
function arredondar(num) {
    if (num <= 500) {
        return Math.round(num / 10) * 10;
    } else {
        return Math.round(num / 500) * 500;
    }
}

arrendondar(4440);
```

Answer (score 1):

Divida  o numero por 10, arredonte o resultado e multiplique por 10 novamente:

```
var number = 33;

alert(Math.round(number / 10) * 10);
```

Com 500 é lógica é semelhante

Em 500 ficaria assim:

```
var number = 1003;

    alert(Math.round(number / 500) * 500);
```